# Создать хранимую процедуру

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно создать хранимую процедуру для генерации скриптов insert-запросов содержимого таблицы, переданной в параметре. Результат:

```
INSERT INTO Сотрудники(id ,Фамилия ,Имя ,Отчество ,Дата_рождения ,Паспорт ,Дата_найма ,Дата_увольнения ,Должность ,Группа ) VALUES('1','Мясников','Всеволод','Алексеевич','1987-01-02','6161 864808','2011-05-03',NULL,'4','4')
```

и т.д. В коде по имени таблицы извлекаю строку с перечнем полей, как извлечь строку со значением перечня полей:

```
create procedure СкриптЗаполненияТаблицы
    @ИмяТаблицы varchar (30)
    as
    1)declare @СписокПолей varchar(8000)=null
    2)declare @СписокЗначений varchar(8000)=null
    3)declare @ИтоговаяСтрока varchar(8000)
    1)select @СписокПолей=isnull(@СписокПолей+', '+name,name)
    from sys.columns 
    where object_id=object_id(@ИмяТаблицы)
    2)select @СписокЗначений=@СписокЗначений+'isnull('+'char(39)'+cast(name as varchar)+'char(39)'+', '+'char(39)'+'char(39)'')'
    from sys.columns 
    where object_id=object_id(@ИмяТаблицы)
    3)set @ИтоговаяСтрока='insert into '+@ИмяТаблицы+'('+@СписокПолей+')'+'values'
    select @СписокПолей
    select @СписокЗначений
    select @ИтоговаяСтрока
  go
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
drop procedure СкриптЗаполненияТаблицы
go
create procedure СкриптЗаполненияТаблицы
@ИмяТаблицы varchar (30)
as
declare @СписокПолей varchar(8000)=null
declare @СписокЗначений varchar(8000)=''
declare @ИтоговаяСтрока varchar(8000)=''
select @СписокПолей=isnull(@СписокПолей+', '+name,name)
from sys.columns 
where object_id=object_id(@ИмяТаблицы)
select @СписокЗначений=@СписокЗначений + ''''''' + isnull(+convert(varchar,'+name+'),''null'')+ '''''''+', '
from sys.columns
where object_id=object_id(@ИмяТаблицы)
set @СписокЗначений=SUBSTRING(@СписокЗначений,1,len(@СписокЗначений)-1)
set @ИтоговаяСтрока='select replace(''insert into '+@ИмяТаблицы+'('+@СписокПолей+')'+' values ('+@СписокЗначений+')'', ''''''null'''''',''null'') from '+@ИмяТаблицы
exec(@ИтоговаяСтрока)
go

exec СкриптЗаполненияТаблицы Сотрудники
```